# Set systemd timer to run every 90 seconds

Tags: linux, bash, timer, systemd

This is a systemd timer file that runs every minute during working days and working hours
How can I make it run every 90 seconds instead of every 1 minute?

```
[Unit]
Description=A timer that runs every minute
Requires=some-service.service

[Timer]
Unit=some-service.service
AccuracySec=1s
OnCalendar=Sat,Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu *-*-* 07..17:00/1:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Comment: It might not be possible. Consider using `sleep` in your `bash` script in some `while` loop. See also [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), [sleep(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sleep.1.html), [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [usleep(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) and the documentation and source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `OnUnitActiveSec=90` to **Timer** section.

From [options description](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html):

> **OnUnitActiveSec=** - Defines a timer relative to when the unit the timer unit is activating was last activated

Also, I would advise you to reduce the **AccuracySec** to 1us (`AccuracySec=1us`) for more accurate performance, if this, of course, is required.

Comment: [Alloces](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11608607/alloces). when I used OnUnitActiveSec, The system ignored my OnCalendar settings. Is there a way to combine both? so, it would fire every 90 seconds and keep the other settings too?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering. Strange, I thought it worked. Then you can change **OnCalendar=** option to `OnCalendar=Sat,Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu *-*-* 07..17:*:*` and add to your *some-service.service* to **Service** section `ExecStopPost=/bin/sleep 90`. In this case, the service will not start until the waiting time has passed. But in this case, there is a possibility that the service will be launched once after the specified time in **OnCalendar**. If this is still relevant and helps you, I will change the answer.